# Isabelle syntax translations: Force eta-expansion?

Tags: syntax, isabelle

Isabelle’s List theory has set up a syntax translation for `filter`:

```
syntax
  -- {* Special syntax for filter *}
  "_filter" :: "[pttrn, 'a list, bool] => 'a list"    ("(1[_<-_./ _])")

translations
  "[x<-xs . P]"== "CONST filter (%x. P) xs"
```

and indeed `term "filter (λ x. ¬(P x)) l"` will nicely print

```
"[x←l . ¬ P x]"  :: "int list"
```

But if the expression is simple, e.g. `ilter (λ x. P x) l`, eta-contraction seems to happen and I get shown

```
"filter P l" :: "int list"
```

Can I somehow force the nice syntax (i.e. `[x←l . P x]`) here as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid eta-contraction by installing an appropriate `print_translation`. There are several examples for binders and tuples in the HOL sources, e.g., for `THE` in `HOL.thy`. They are easy to adapt to `filter`, for example:

```
print_translation {*
  [(@{const_syntax filter}, fn _ => fn [Abs abs, xs] =>
    let val (x, t) = Syntax_Trans.atomic_abs_tr' abs
    in Syntax.const @{syntax_const "_filter"} $ x $ t $ xs end)]
*}  -- {* To avoid eta-contraction of body *}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. Now I just have to understand it and apply to the syntax I’m creating :-).
Do you think this is worth to enter `HOL/List.thy`? It seems it would make the output more consistent and predictable.

Comment: I am not sure whether this should be put into `HOL`, maybe into `~~/src/HOL/Library/OptionalSugar`. I personally prefer to read `filter P xs` instead of `[x←l. P x]`. Unfortunately, a number of Isabelle tools eta-expand such functions (e.g. `induction` and `simp` with the congruence rule for `filter`). Therefore, adding it to the theory `List` should be discussed publicly first.